# Filling an Entity Reference programatically

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I am creating a node programatically and one of the fields in the node is an entity reference field referencing a user.

I am using the guide from https://www.drupal.org/node/1388922 and the general consensus i gather is that I need to do something like;

```
$node->field_customer_nid[$node->language][] = array(
'target_id' => $form_state['values']['entity id'],
'target_type' => 'node',
```

);

My question is where do i pass the values for the target entity(basically the uid)in that array. Is it the target_id or the entity_id because my attempts with either of those is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better approach is using entity metadata wrapper.

Below snippet is copied from drupal.org [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/entity-metadata-wrappers)

```php
$containing_node = node_load($nid);
$w_containing_node = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $containing_node);

$nids_to_set = array(42, 23);
$w_containing_node->field_entity_reference_field->set($nids_to_set);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the entity id and the entity type. The example is referencing a node but you want to reference a user.

Try this:

```
$node->field_customer_nid[$node->language][] = array(
  'target_id' => $entity_id,
);
```

$entity_id should hold the referenced entity id.

Comment: That's not quite right - there's only one field column (target_id), the target type is a setting for the whole field and can't be set at runtime so-to-speak. Just providing a valid entity id for target_id is all that's necessary

Comment: Oops, sorry, I didn't check it... as is a wrng answer I'm going to delete it, do you want to repost your comment in the question or as a new answer?