# How to set a node reference programmatically?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I'm creating a new node and attempting to the values of the fields programmatically. I cannot seem to figure out how to set a value for a node reference field, the widget type is autocomplete and it is set to unlimited values.

Here is my code to create the new node and an entity metadata wrapper

```
// Create the communication node and set the current user as the author
$new_comm = entity_create('node', array('type' => 'comm', 'uid' => $uid));
// create a wrapper for the new communication
$nc_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $new_comm);
// then I set some other field values via the $nc_wrapper
```

I cannot seem to set the value for the node reference field `field_comm_relationship`. I have tried all manner of setting the value including the following (`$oc_wrapper` wraps a different node type that also has a node reference):

**I tried inserting it straight from the `$oc_wrapper`**

```
$nc_wrapper->field_comm_relationship = $oc_wrapper->field_call_site_ref->value();
```

**I tried using the set method**

```
$nc_wrapper->field_comm_relationship->set($oc_wrapper->field_call_site_ref->value());
```

**I tried both of the previous while accessing the actual `nid` value**

```
$nc_wrapper->field_comm_relationship->set($oc_wrapper->field_call_site_ref->value()->nid);
```

**and**

```
$nc_wrapper->field_comm_relationship = $oc_wrapper->field_call_site_ref->value()->nid;
```

**I tried to make the input an array**

```
$site_nid = ['und' => [ 0 => ['nid' => (int) $oc_wrapper->field_call_site_ref->value()->nid]]];
$nc_wrapper->field_comm_relationship = $site_nid;
```

**I tried using the `node_load` function instead of EMW**

```
$node = node_load('node', $nc_wrapper->nid->value());
$site_nid = $oc_wrapper->field_call_site_ref->value()->nid;
$node->field_comm_relationship['und'][0]['nid'] = $site_nid;
node_save($node);
```

As suggested I do call `save()` later in my code, but it's not making it there because it hits a fatal error. For instance if I run this code

```
$nc_wrapper->field_comm_relationship = (int) $oc_wrapper->field_call_site_ref->value()->nid;
```

I get this error

```
EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. 
Be sure it matches the required data type and format. 
Value at node()->field_comm_relationship: 713511. in EntityMetadataWrapper->set() 
(line 122 of /vagrant/sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc)
```

Comment: What is an example value for `$oc_wrapper->field_call_site_ref->value()`?

Comment: Is it an int? an array? an object?

Comment: It's an object. Specifically the node object of the node being referenced.

Comment: You get that same error when you do `$nc_wrapper->field_comm_relationship = $oc_wrapper->field_call_site_ref->value();` `$nc_wrapper->save();`? Is `field_comm_relationship` a multivalue field?

Comment: If I run that code I get an SQL error:  PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '), ('node', '713866', '1158104', 'comm', 'field_site_handset_serial', 'und', 'Ar' at line 1: INSERT INTO {field_data_field_comm_relationship} (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, language, field_comm_relationship_nid) VALUES...` and then it lists a BUNCH of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating the value in your entity metadata wrapper you need to be sure to also call the `save()` method to save your change. See [this documentation on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers#example-value-set-save).

Since you have an object, and not an id, the following should work.

```
// Set value for a single value field.
$nc_wrapper->field_comm_relationship = $oc_wrapper->field_call_site_ref->value();
```

or

```
// Set value for a multivalue field. Make sure to pass an array of objects.
$nc_wrapper->field_comm_relationship = [$oc_wrapper->field_call_site_ref->value()];
```

or

```
// Append an additional value to a multivalue field.
$nc_wrapper->field_comm_relationship[] = $oc_wrapper->field_call_site_ref->value();
```

and finally

```
// Save the host entity.
$nc_wrapper->save();
```

If you have ids, check out [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/207658/48114). You can get an id instead of an object from the entity metadata wrapper like `$oc_wrapper->field_call_site_ref->raw()` instead of `->value()`;

Additional info for entity metadata wrappers can be found in this [Death to Field Arrays!](https://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/death-field-arrays/) article.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response. I do call `save()` later in my code, but it's not making it that far before a fatal error. I have updated my question.

Comment: I've updated this answer. I hope this resolves this for you. I think your issues were because your field is a multivalue field and not a single value field.

Comment: `$nc_wrapper->field_comm_relationship[] = $oc_wrapper->field_call_site_ref->value();` that got it. Thanks!